# How to fire $.post when inside function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I want to fire Jquery to execute php code inside different file. However I cannot find a way to get the Jquery command to execute.

I am using wordpress.

My code inside functions.php

```html
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'mycustom_wp_footer' );    //adding funtion for each form buttom to fire when pressed

    function mycustom_wp_footer() {     //function form each form button to fire when button pressed
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var wpcf7Elm = document.querySelectorAll( '.wpcf7' );
            wpcf7Elm.forEach(function(formr){
            formr.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
                    //if ('wpcf7-f101-p97-o1' == event.detail.unitTag) {    //when button inside form with this unitTag is pressed do code bellow

                        var gen3_name = "25";
                        //tis code is not working
                        $(document).ready(function(){   //adding ajax, Jquery to send data to .php file for php function to execute
                            $.post("gen3.php", name: gen3_name);
                        });
                    //tis code is not working
             
                    var idform = event.detail.unitTag;
                    alert (idform);
            }, false ); })
        </script>
```

My code inside gen3.php

```html
global $wpdb;

if (isset($_POST['name'])) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    
    if ($name == "25") {

        $wpdb->update('Gen3', array('tvalue' => 1,), array('id' => 25), array('%d'), array('%d'));

    }

}
```

Comment: Using `$(document).ready` in that place makes little sense. This code only runs when the `wpcf7submit` event fires, and at that point, the ready event of the document is already ages in the past. Just call `$.post`, without wrapping it into document ready.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Sadly, it´s not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell me what output do you get in your console? Any error or warning?
I think your code will be placed before attaching the JQuery file. Put the priority of the hook to a high number which means low priority and it will be placed after attaching the jquery.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'mycustom_wp_footer', 0, 999999 );
```

Also because of loading JQuery NoConflict or some other plugins, You might need to use JQuery.method() instead of $.method.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I tried all of your suggestions.
Console output is: _ ** "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing )" ** _ after argument list. Which is strange, because I checked my code multiple times. Also it seems that when I look where the error is the script is not updated and still old. Even when the server file is updated.

Comment: Did you check other plugins and dependencies? Because the error might be for another plugin. Otherwise, it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: It seems like it. But when I click at the error it shows me this line: _$.post("gen3.php", name: gen3_name);_ (the problem is here according to the wordpress)